# Set the locale of the PostgreSQL cluster when installing on Ubuntu

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, locale

When installing PostgreSQL from `apt` on Ubuntu, the command `initdb` to initialize the cluster is done automatically, and [the locale is set from the enviroment](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/locale.html).

I like to have my system in `en_US.UTF8`, but initialize the cluster in a different locale.

For that I've tried to set the environment variable locally for apt

```
LOCALE=es_ES.UTF-8 LC_MESSAGES=C apt install postgresql-15
```

but it's not working. `apt` output shows:

```
/usr/lib/postgresql/15/bin/initdb -D /var/lib/postgresql/15/main --auth-local peer --auth-host scram-sha-256 --no-instructions

The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
The default text search configuration will be set to "english".
```

For completion a simplified version of my provision script looks like this:

```
MY_LOCALE="es_ES.UTF-8"

# Allow the system to use $MY_LOCALE
sed -i "s/^# ${MY_LOCALE} UTF-8/${MY_LOCALE} UTF-8/" /etc/locale.gen
locale-gen

# Uncomment these lines if $MY_LOCALE must be the default
# update-locale --reset LANG="${MY_LOCALE}" LC_CTYPE="${MY_LOCALE}"
# export LANG="${MY_LOCALE}"
# export LC_TYPE="${MY_LOCALE}"

# Set the locale locally to apt command
LOCALE="${MY_LOCALE}" LC_MESSAGES=C apt install postgresql-15
```

Is there any way to pass locale variables to apt/initdb on installation?

**Update.**

As the question is closed and no answers can be added I edit to explain my actual workaround:

```
MY_LOCALE="es_ES.UTF-8"

# Allow the system to use $MY_LOCALE
sed -i "s/^# ${MY_LOCALE} UTF-8/${MY_LOCALE} UTF-8/" /etc/locale.gen
locale-gen

# Uncomment these lines if $MY_LOCALE must be the default
# update-locale --reset LANG="${MY_LOCALE}" LC_CTYPE="${MY_LOCALE}"
# export LANG="${MY_LOCALE}"
# export LC_TYPE="${MY_LOCALE}"

# Backup default enviroment variables
BCK_LANG="${LANG}"
BCK_LC_CTYPE="${LC_CTYPE}"
BCK_LC_MESSAGES="${LC_MESSAGES}"

# Set the desired locale for PostgreSQL as default for the system
update-locale --reset LANG="${MY_LOCALE}" LC_CTYPE="${MY_LOCALE}" LC_MESSAGES=C

# Install PostgreSQL
apt install postgresql-15

# Restore default locale
update-locale --reset LANG="${BCK_LANG}" LC_CTYPE="${BCK_LC_CTYPE}" LC_MESSAGES="${BCK_LC_MESSAGES}"

unset BCK_LANG
unset BCK_LC_CTYPE
unset BCK_LC_MESSAGES
```

Comment: Maybe you have `LC_ALL` set? That would override `LC_xyz` and `LANG`: *the following environment variables are consulted in this order until one is found to be set: LC_ALL, LC_COLLATE (or the variable corresponding to the respective category), LANG. If none of these environment variables are set then the locale defaults to C.*

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but `LC_ALL` was not set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think so.

The behavior of the Ubuntu packages has always annoyed me. Do what I do: drop the cluster that the packages create automatically and create it again with the configuration you want.